# Python flask generator function not working with JQuery-mobile

Tags: python, jquery-mobile, flask, generator, partial-page-refresh

I've been stuck with the following problem for a while, and i can't seem to get it to work on this Python flask web application i've been developing:

1) my flask view -> obtains image data from a local database and passes the data via a generator to a template

My flask route/view code:

```
@app.route(@app.route('/viewer',methods=['GET'])
def viewer():
    archive = request.args.get('filepath')
    arc = rarTools()
    pagetotal = arc.pageTotal(archive)
    def g():
        for n in range(pagetotal):
            data = arc.getPageb64(archive,n+1)
            print(n+1)
            yield data
   return Response(stream_template('viewer.html',data=g()))
```

2) My HTML template with JQuery Mobile UI obtains this data and simply displays all the image data on 1 page

My HTML viewer.html **with** JQuery mobile UI:

```
<body style="background-color: black">
    <div data-role="page" class="page" id="mainpage" data-theme="b">
        <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
            <div id="frame" align="middle" style="width: 100%">
                {% for page in data %}
                    <img id="page_img" src="data:image/png;base64,{{ page }}" width="80px" height="auto"/>
                {% endfor %}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

My HTML viewer.html **WITHOUT** JQuery mobile UI:

```
<body style="background-color: black">   
    <div id="frame" align="middle" style="width: 100%">
        {% for page in data %}
            <img id="page_img" src="data:image/png;base64,{{ page }}" width="80px" height="auto"/>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
</body>
```

My problem is how long it takes to load pages when there are many images in my database. The load time is vastly different when I use JQuery Mobile and when I don't:
Because i'm using a generator to pass the data to the template, the images are loaded dynamically with the page loading immediately and each page appearing as the image data is generated on the flask back-end when I don't use JQuery Mobile to style the page.
When I use JQuery Mobile on the other hand, the page only loads once all the image data is passed even though i'm using a generator.
How can I get my JQuery Mobile template page to refresh after every yield, so that

1. The page loads immediately irrespective of image count?
2. The pages refreshes after each new image data "yield" so the the images are  loaded dynamically? - like it works when I don't use JQuery Mobile?

I am aware that it has something to do with the - either: 'pageinit' or 'pageload' events with Jquery Mobile, but for the life of me, i can't seem to get the above code to work!!

Any assistance would be much appreciated, thanks in advance!